# If $w^T x = 0$ is invariant, then $A^Tw = \lambda w$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, set-invariance

I'm stuck finding a counterexample of this exercise. Let the linear system $\dot{x} = Ax$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of $A$. I know if $w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $A^{T}w = \lambda w$, then $w^T x = 0$ is invariant with respect of the flow of the differential equation.

Is it true that if $w^T x = 0$ is invariant, then $A^Tw = \lambda w$?

My answer is that is a false statement, but I cannot find a counterexample to prove my hypothesis. I guess, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, some matrix such that $det(A)=0$ would help me, but I do not know how to proceed.

Any help?

Comment: An invariant is associated with a zero eigenvalue of $A$. Would that help?

Comment: Then the equality does not hold, right?

Comment: Set $u(t)=w^Tx(t)$. Then $\dot u=λu$ and the claim follows, the zero function is a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such counterexample, the statement is true. Let $V(x)=w^T x$, $w\ne 0$. If the hyperplane
$$S=\{x\in\mathbb R^n:\; V(x)=0 \}$$
is invariant, then the derivative along the trajectories $\dot V= w^T\dot x= w^T Ax$ is zero on $S$:
$$
\forall x\in S\quad \dot V =0.
$$
Thus we have
$$
\forall x\in\mathbb R^n\quad w^T x =0 \Rightarrow w^T Ax=0.
$$
If $w^T A\ne 0$, then $\{x\in\mathbb R^n:\; w^T Ax=0 \}$ is also a hyperplane. It contains the hyperplane $S$, and hence coincides with it. If $w^T x=0$ and $w^T Ax=0$ are the equations of the same hyperplane, then $w^T A=\lambda w^T$.

If $w^TA=0$, then also $w^T A=\lambda w^T$, where $\lambda=0$.

Comment: I have one question, how we can conclude that the hyperplane coincide?

Comment: @Bayesian guy We know that $S=\{x\in\mathbb R^n:\; w^T x=0 \}$ and $Q=\{x\in\mathbb R^n:\; w^T Ax=0 \}$ are vector spaces, $\dim(S)=\dim(Q)=n-1$, $S$ is a subspace of $Q$. Take some basis in $S$, it will be a basis in $Q$ too. If the bases are the same, then the spaces are the same

Comment: You are right! Also, I was confused with the statement. Here we did not use the fact that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue right?

Comment: @Bayesian guy The equality $A^Tw = \lambda w$, $w\ne 0$ exactly means that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue. We have actually proved that such an eigenvalue exists

Comment: You are right... My bad. Many thanks!